# Does cvQueryFrame have buffer for frames in advance?

Tags: c++, c, opencv

If i do:

```
while(1) { 
   //retrieve image from the camera
   webCamImage=cvQueryFrame(camera) // where 'camera' is cvCreateCameraCapture(0)

   //do some heavy processing on the image that may take around half a second
   funcA()
}
```

Now when I go to consecutive iterations, it seems that webCamImage lags !

Even if i move the camera, webCamImage takes long time to get updated to the new field of view, and it keeps showing and processing previous field of view camera frames.

I am assuming that cvQuery has some buffer that retrieves the frames.

Can you please advise me on how to get the updated camera view each iteration ?

Many thanks

Comment: Consider that perhaps layers lower than opencv might have buffers beyond your control, so it might not be so easy. Perhaps you could create a thread for processing that calls [`cvRetrieveFrame`](http://opencv.jp/opencv-1.0.0_org/docs/ref/opencvref_highgui.htm#decl_cvRetrieveFrame) only when needed (beware of synchronization issues) and a main thread that calls `cvGrabFrame` regularly.

Comment: It is very difficult to answer your question because OpenCV can use up to 15 different APIs for video-capturing (See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7247475/opencv-2-3-c-qtgui-problem-initializing-some-specific-usb-devices-and-setups/7264572#7264572) for details). Please post more info about your OS and OpenCV version (which binaries you have downloaded or cmake output if you have complied OpenCV yourself).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cvQueryFrame` is just a wrapper that calls 2 other functions: `cvGrabFrame`, which gets data from the camera very quickly, and `cvRetrieveFrame`, which uncompresses this data and puts it into an `IplImage`. If you need frames captured *immediately,* just grab the frame, and retrieve it for processing later.

See http://opencv.jp/opencv-1.0.0_org/docs/ref/opencvref_highgui.htm FMI

Having said that, though, I use `cvQueryFrame` with a typical webcam, and I have no trouble getting dozens of frames per second. Any chance that the part that's lagging is actually in your `funcA()` call? *edit: from the comment in your code, I see that `funcA()` is indeed the slow part. If it takes half a second to execute, you'll only get a new frame from `cvQUeryFrame` every half second, just as you describe. Try either making `funcA` faster, or put it in a separate thread.*

and as a friendly reminder, the `IplImage` returned by `cvQueryFrame`/`cvRetrieveFrame` should not be modified or deleted by the user; it's part of OpenCV's internal system for storing things, and if you're doing anything interesting with it, you should make a copy. I don't know if you're doing this already, but I certainly did it wrong when I started out.