# How do I get a list of webcam devices using opencv?

Tags: c++, windows, opencv

I am using OpenCV2.2 with videoInput.  I want to upgrade to OpenCV2.3.1 where videoInput has apparently been merged into OpenCV2.3.

My problem is that there doesn't appear to be a listdevices() function to return all the video sources available.

Does anybody know the new equivalent?

Comment: can you put the full code about it? i'm trying to list all webcam devices, but unsuccessfully

Answer (score 10):

As you said videoinput has been merged in OpenCV since 2.3rc.

Looking at the relevant [source](https://code.ros.org/trac/opencv/browser/trunk/opencv/modules/highgui/src/cap_dshow.cpp?rev=5506) videoinput appears to be in highgui as the OpenCV changelog specifies. Though whether your OpenCV is built with it enabled is a configurable option in Cmake (The option is `WITH_VIDEOINPUT` and also requires it be a WIN32 build, see [here](https://code.ros.org/trac/opencv/browser/trunk/opencv/CMakeLists.txt?rev=7265)).

OpenCV calls listdevices internally  as `VI.listDevices()` in the implementation of `CvCaptureCAM_DShow::open` and the videoInput Class is a protected member of CvCaptureCAM_DShow.

You can get access listdevices function using

```
 CvCapture* capture = cvCaptureFromCAM( CV_CAP_DSHOW );
 capture->VI.listDevices();
```

Comment: What is the CMAKE option to enable VI? Can you please explain? I trie dyour sample code snippet. It says VI is not a valid object.

Answer (score 3):

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7322939/how-to-count-cameras-in-opencv-2-3) StackOverflow answer. It is currently not supported by OpenCV because it is cross platform, and camera enumeration is very platform specific (e.g., v4l2 enumerates differently than DirectShow). But, someone submitted an [enhancement request](https://code.ros.org/trac/opencv/ticket/935) against version 2.2 a while back.

Answer (score 1):

I coded a class that allows to enumerate all the devices by using the DirectShow interface and enumerators. While it will only work on Windows, it will allow you to obtain a list of "friendly device names" and the ids that you need to create, for example a VideoCapture object.

The code is here:

https://github.com/studiosi/OpenCVDeviceEnumerator