# Capturing video from SMI Grabber Device using Opencv C++

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, video

I am trying to capture a video from an SMI grabber device using opencv c++. The line VideoCapture cap(0) obtains video from web cam. How do I get the feed from the device that I have connected.

Answer (score 0):

From openCV docs

> VideoCapture
>
> public VideoCapture(int device)
>
> Parameters:
> device - id of the opened video capturing device (i.e. a camera index). If there is a single camera connected, just pass 0.

As per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7322939/how-to-count-cameras-in-opencv-2-3) answer, it's not possible at the moment to enumerate devices via OpenCV however you could try passing 1 and see if the SMI device is found there.

Comment: typically that will work, but there is a bug in openCV/videoInput for many grabber cards. If grabbing works with DirectShow (e.g. graphstudio or VLC) but not in openCV, this bug is still present but can easily be fixed.