# Open CV Capture with external capture card

Tags: video, opencv, video-capture

Is there a way to capture with OpenCV from an external capture device ( e.g. AJA IO HD) or any other digitizer (e.g. analog-to-digital converter)? Or in other words, what do I need to be able to capture (drivers, workflow) ? If there is an easy way to capture with Python (same setup), I would also be glad to hear about it. And it would need to be for Mac.

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there are quite a few capture devices supported by OpenCV.  The [`VideoCapture` API](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#videocapture) gives you access to supported capture cards, provided the appropriate libraries are compiled in at build time.

This answer provides a list of platforms and backend APIs:

- [OpenCV 2.3 (C++,QtGui), Problem Initializing some specific USB Devices and Setups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7247475/opencv-2-3-c-qtgui-problem-initializing-some-specific-usb-devices-and-setup/7264572#7264572)

For Mac support, the QuickTime backend should provide the best driver support.  I believe both AJA and Blackmagic capture cards should support this.  You can verify the QuickTime capture support using a tool such as HackTV.

The Python bindings should provide equivalent access to control these features.

Comment: Great. Thanks for the helpful answer. So Quicktime would work I guess, but from what I understand it is optional and I have to turn that on during the build. Does anybody have experience with this building :) Thanks again. Sorry, one more thing, Where can I get HackTV. It seems all links for this are dead.

Comment: These build instructions http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/Mac_OS_X_OpenCV_Port should work. You should probably check to see if you need to use QuickTime or QTKit capturing first.  Download FiendishThings from ADC and look at the `vdig` components.  Assuming it's QuickTime, try using MungGrab or BrideOfMungGrab to view.  I don't know what's happened to HackTV but I guess it's retired.